# Each row has its own heading in android gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am developing an app with android gridview. My gridview consists of 10 rows and 7 columns. Actually this is a color chart so each element in the gridview should be of different color. I have created the elements in the drawable folder.The problem is that I need to put a heading on each row and not for each element.
Suppose I have a heading like "head" then I have to put the "head" on the top of the left most element in the row.This is what i exactly want:
[image]

What do I have to do for achieving this ?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);

        view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
    view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this library? [Sticky Grid Headers](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/)

Comment: how can we implement sticky grid headers.?

Comment: Download the library. It contains a working example. Replicate that in your app. And if you face some difficulty, then post a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using drawables directly in your adapter, you could try using a custom layout which has a heading `TextView` and an image `ImageView` under it.

Now In the adpater, in the getview(), you could set the drawable to the ImageView and set the heading to the elements in positions 0,7,14... and so on and for all other positions have the heading `Gone`.

EDIT: (explaining further)

in your custom layout, have the visibility of header as `Gone`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   if(position==0 || position%7==0){
     // modify header here 
     // set visibility to visible here 
   }
   else
      // set visibility to gone here

 // add image view here

}
```

Comment: How do we get element positions.? please dont mind I am new to android

Comment: You must be using an adapter with your gridview, the getview() method gives you the position of the view, indexed from 0.
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {}

Comment: can you please give me sample code snippet? i have created imageview and put its background but heading is showing above each element's top

Comment: yes it will show because we need to display it only for the first column, are you using an adapter for your gridview ? If yes then in the adapter there is a function you need to override called getView(). Also can you tell me exactly where are setting the imageView ?

Comment: yes I have an overriding getView Function. what i have to do in getView.?

Comment: hey can I have your mail ID i will send you the details.?

Comment: if you dont mind lets do this on StackOverflow, for the community!.. Ok, check my Edited answer.

Comment: Hey see my getView method now what i have to do.?

Comment: Hey what does the if condition means .?

Comment: since we need only the first element in each row to have the heading, the positions become 0 , 7 ,14 and so on. position modulo 7 will return 0 for 7, 14, and so on

Comment: Hey It Works..:) thank you soo much..:) but one problem the alignment of the row changes. how can i change the alignment of the text view .?

Comment: so instead of making the view Gone, make it invisible. this will work

Comment: ohk lemme check. anyways thank you .:)

Comment: again having a problem that when scrolling the grid view the alignment changes that is some elements are going invisible some are not in correct position.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a layout xml file containing a `TextView` and `ImageView`
set the text only for 0th row elements and leave it blank for the others.

Comment: How set the text only for 0th row.? how can we control each elements.?